# rvalue for universal reference and std::forward

Tags: c++

I am going through "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers, and found 2 contradicting statements.

In Item 1, under Case 2: ParamType is a Universal Reference:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param); // param is now a universal reference
f(27); // 27 is rvalue, so T is int,
 // param's type is therefore int&&
```

So, this means that `param`'s type is `int&&`, but when it comes to `std::forward`(Item 23):

```
void process(const Widget& lvalArg); // process lvalues
void process(Widget&& rvalArg); // process rvalues

template<typename T> // template that passes
void logAndProcess(T&& param) // param to process
{
 process(std::forward<T>(param));
}

Widget w;
logAndProcess(w); // call with lvalue
logAndProcess(std::move(w)); // call with rvalue
```

Here, it is mentioned that for both calls, `param` is an lvalue in the definition for `logAndProcess(T&&)`.

But according to Universal reference, shouldn't `param`'s type for `logAndProcess(T&&)` be an rvalue when the argument is rvalue (`std::move(w)`)?

I am not able to understand the 2 statements and it feels contradicting.

Comment: "Here it is mentioned that for both calls, param is lvalue...." I dont see it. The comment on the first call says `//call with lvalue` on the second call it says `// call with rvalue`

Comment: you mean `param` ? If it has a name its not a `rvalue`

Comment: An rvalue reference is still a lvalue.  Anything with a name is a lvalue.

Comment: `param` is always an lvalue because it has a name.  The thing it references may be an lvalue or an rvalue and you can recover that information using `std::forward<T>`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I meant to say that for both the calls, inside logAndProcess, param is lvalue

Comment: The terms "_lvalue/rvalue reference_" and "_lvalue/rvalue_" are related but not interchangeable or one a shortened form of the other. The first are categories for the _type_ of a variable/member. The second are _value categories_ for _expressions_. This distinction is very important and seems to be overlooked by most when introduced to the topic. So a variable with a rvalue reference type can be named as an expression that has lvalue value category.

Comment: btw the official term is "forwarding reference"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number if it has a name its not a `rvalue` - I did not get this. When `f(27)` is called, inside the function is it not an `rvalue`? If it is not an `rvalue` then what is the point of universal reference?

Comment: actually the fact that `param` is not a rvalue is why forwarding references and `std::forward` exist. Without `std::forward` and the forwarding reference `process(param);` will always call  `void process(const Widget& lvalArg);` because `param` is a `lvalue`.

Comment: @Rogmier *"When f(27) is called, inside the function is it not an rvalue?"* Value category (lvalue-ness/rvalue-ness) isn't a property of an object, but rather a property of an expression (which is a part of the program source code that designates an object). `27` is an rvalue, but `param` (in `f`) is an lvalue, though both refer to the same object. It also helps to understand that [expressions never have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1).

Comment: this is a good reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand you refer to the text which follows the given example:

> When we call `logAndProcess` with an lvalue, we naturally expect that lvalue to be forwarded to `process` as an lvalue, and when we call `logAndProcess` with an rvalue, we expect the rvalue overload of `pro cess` to be invoked.
>
> But param, like all function parameters, is an lvalue..

The trick here is that no matter what kind of reference `param` is, it's always an lvalue (even if it's an rvalue reference). To better understand that, you should wrap your mind around idea that value category is not a variable attribute, it's an expression attribute and referring to **any** variable in your code always is an expression that can have **only** lvalue category no matter what type the variable is of:

```cpp
int value;
int* pointer = &value;
int& reference = value;
const int& constReference = 10;
int&& rvalueReference = 20;
```

Here all consequent use of `value`, `pointer`, `reference`, `constReference` and `rvalueReference` produce an **lvalue** in your code, but the literals (`10`, `20`) are **prvalues** which can initialise variables and parameters which expect such a value category (`const int&` and `int&&`)

Comment: Then what is the point of universal reference? In the book, universal reference deduces param type to be rvalue reference if rvalue is passed as an argument. But as you said, "no matter what kind of reference param is, it's always an lvalue (even if it's an rvalue reference)"

Comment: lvalue references and rvalue references both have lvalue category when referred to in code. rvalue and rvalue reference are not the same

Comment: @TheDreamsWind address-of operator returns an rvalue.

Comment: @appleapple you are right. my bad.

Comment: @Rogmier The point of universal references is that they can be initialized by either an lvalue or rvalue expression, and via `std::forward` you can turn them back into the value category that was used to initialize them.